# Amazon ASIN and Category

Tags: data-request

On Amazon, clearly, there is a tree where all the leaves are the products and you can narrow down a category to find the products.

For example, what I am looking for is actually under the category `Cell Phones & Accessories`, and then `Cell Phones` and then `Unlocked Cell Phones`.

Is there an up-to-date public dataset that has the mapping between category and ASIN (Amazon Stock ID)? so one can avoid scraping a certain category page by page?

[image]

Comment: The answer to this SO question doesnt get you all the way to your answer but it at least should help you get a full picture of the "leaves" and maybe use the API to get which items go to each leaf.

Comment: Another thought (but not full answer) is instead of scraping product pages, use the `Sitemap`s (and downstream sitemaps) linked to from the bottom of http://amazon.com/robots.txt

Comment: @Skram, I agree it is a great idea, I tried to parse all the sitemaps and turned out I only get 200K valid product URLs in the end, which is much less than I expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Amazon Product API to find the category breakdown on Amazon and corresponding products 4 sale.

This link explains how items for sale are organized under the API:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_OrganizationofItemsforSaleonAmazon.html

This is the general link to the API:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/GSG/Welcome.html