# Ecommerce ( amazon, ebay ) dataset

Tags: data-request

I am doing a project and I need large datasets for working.
I want dataset of a dynamic weighted graph. Is there any place I can get them? I can give a signed declaration of not leaking it publicly.

I want a dataset of several timestamps. In each timestamp data, I want a relationship between either customers that buy together/products that are bought together/a customer that buys a product. These can be the possible relationships. And a weight should be associated with each such relationship. The weight can be for example, at what frequence the product is bought/price of the product. Anything like this. It is perfectly alright if the products or the user information is encoded by an id or so. No private information I want

Comment: You may want to check out the answer to this related question: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3671/amazon-asin-and-category

Comment: Qin, what exactly do you want? Product descriptions? Customers descriptions? Reviews? Transactions?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, ok, so, I want a dataset of several timestamps. In each timestamp data, I want a relationship between either customers that buy together/products that are bought together/a customer that buys a product. These can be the possible relationships. And a weight should be associated with each such relationship. The weight can be for example, at what frequence the product is bought/price of the product. Anything like this.

Comment: Also, it is perfectly alright if the products or the user information is encoded by an id or so. No private information I want.